# Сервер для андроид приложений, что посоветуете?

Tags: android, сервер

Нужен простой сервер, просто протестировать приложение, отправить запрос на сервер, и получить ответ с него, и всё.

Comment: А свой локальный не подходит? В принципе серверную часть можно хоть на php написать, а серверов, которые его хостят - вагон и тележка. Для тестов хватит с головой.

Comment: @Seth, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

jetty, tomcat, parse.com, google engine

Comment: Нужно специально для них скачивать спец. программы для удаленного управления или просто зарегистрировался - и готово?

Comment: Мне понравился сайт www.parse.com, он дает бесплатный период? А jetty и tomcat? GE пока откажусь, нет кредитки.

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял, то NGROK должен прекрасно подойти. Данная тулза предоставляет возможность "провести" туннель между локальным хостом и глобально сетью, позволяя тем самым получать доступ через глобальный домен.

Достаточно просто зарегистрироваться, скачать тулзу. Далее вам выдадут аутентификационный. Подробнее тут : https://ngrok.com/

Answer (score 0):

Работаете на Windows?

Тогда просто делаете локальный сервер с помощью пакета программ Denwer. Установка там очень простая. Постоянно пользуюсь им для тестов изменений сайта.

Вот здесь можно скачать Denwer: http://www.denwer.ru/

По совпадению, сейчас учусь делать C# приложения, тоже собираюсь протестировать серверную часть (в моем случае, отправить с десктопного приложения запрос на сервер для добавления записей в БД). Уже создал БД, подготовил приложение, сейчас делаю серверную часть, которая будет принимать запросы :)

Answer (score 0):

Можете также почитать здесь:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Тут написано, как реализовать локальный сервер с помощью WampServer и как его законектить с андроидом.